# What does it mean in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, statelesswidget

**1.**`const GreenFrog({ Key key }) : super(key: key);`,

**2.**`@override` ,

**3.**`Widget build(BuildContext context)`

what does these three things referring to?

```
class GreenFrog extends StatelessWidget {
  const GreenFrog({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: const Color(0xFF2DBD3A));
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you read [The Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials

Answer (score 4):

1. `GreenFrog({ Key key }) : super(key: key)` This is the constructor for the `GreenFrog` class and its super constructor respectively. The super constructor is the constructor of its parent, the `StatelessWidget` (see inheritance in OOP)
2. `@override` is an annotation that indicates that this method is being overridden (since its also defined in the super class (`StatelessWidget`)). This makes so that GreenFrog will have its own build method and won't use its parent build method.
3. `Widget build(BuildContext context)` is a function/method that takes in a `context` and returns a `Widget`. The Flutter Framework expect your widgets to have this method defined so it can render them on the screen.

This is too much to explain in a single answer and all those questions relate to OOP (Object Oriented Programming), so you should try to understand them first. Try the documentation or some book. [Here](https://www.syncfusion.com/ebooks/flutter-succinctly) is a small and free book for beginners. It may help you.